# Probability of crossing a point in a given time window

Tags: probability

The probability of a car passing a certain intersection in a 20 minute windows is 0.9. What is the probability of a car passing the intersection in a 5 minute window? (Assuming a constant probability throughout)

Comment: If you are considering one-fourth the time, and the probaility is "constant throughout", then wouldn't it just be one-fourth the probability?

Comment: @MikePierce You're right. Stationarity in independent intervals make more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Define events:
\begin{eqnarray*}
C_{20} &=& \text{"A car passes in a 20-minute window"} \\
C_5 &=& \text{"A car passes in a 5-minute window"}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
0.9 &=& P(C_{20}) \\
&=& 1-P(C_{20}^c) \\
&=& 1-P(C_5^c)^4 \qquad\text{(assuming independence of cars passing)} \\
&=& 1-(1-P(C_5))^4 \\
\therefore (1-P(C_5))^4 &=& 0.1 \\
1-P(C_5) &=& (0.1)^{1/4} \\
P(C_5) &=& 1-(0.1)^{1/4} \\
&\approx& 0.438.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @ Mick A :  $C_{20}$ can be union of 4 disjoint events: a car passes only in 1st 5-min window, only in 2nd 5-min window and so on. Assuming $x=P(C_{5})$ we have $x(1-x)^3 + (1-x)x(1-x)^2+..=4x(1-x)^3=P(C_{20})=0.9$. Interestingly $x=0.438$ is not a solution for this equation. Can you help me understand what is going wrong!

Comment: @KGhatak I take $C_{20}$ to mean _at least_ $1$ car in $20$ minutes, not _exactly_ $1$ car, which I take to be your reasoning. That's why I switch to event complements because "no car in $20$ mins" equals "no car in $5$ mins" repeated $4$ times.

Comment: @ Mick A : If we consider $C_{20}$ as the event that exactly one car passing in 20-min window, then still the anomaly remains. Could you pls help!

Comment: @KGhatak We presume the possibility of any number (0,1,2,...) of cars occurring in a given time period. If $x=P(C_5)=P(\text{exactly $1$ car in $5$ mins})$ then what you want for the other three 5-min intervals is $P(0 \text{ cars in $5$ mins})$ which is not equal to $1-x$ because $1-x=P(\text{Number of cars in $5$ mins is $0$ or at least $2$})$.

Comment: @ Mick A : This is awesome explanation. Hats off to you.