# Probability of crossing a point in a given time window - Follow Up

Tags: probability

Referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016268/probability-of-crossing-a-point-in-a-given-time-window) (i.e. The probability of a car passing a certain intersection in a 20 minute windows is 0.9. What is the probability of a car passing the intersection in a 5 minute window? Assume a constant probability throughout.):

An ubiquitous solution is to solve $(1-x)^4 = 1-0.9$ where $x=P(C_{5})$. The solution to this is $x=0.438$.

However, if I consider $C_{20}$ as union of 4 disjoint events: a car passes only in 1st 5-min window, only in 2nd 5-min window and so on. Then we've  $x(1-x)^3 + (1-x)x(1-x)^2+..=4x(1-x)^3=P(C_{20})=0.9$. Interestingly, $x=0.438$ is not a solution of this equation. 
Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing here!!

Note: I've taken the event notation from the cited question as,
\begin{eqnarray*}
C_{20} &=& \text{"A car passes in a 20-minute window"} \\
C_5 &=& \text{"A car passes in a 5-minute window"}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

The probability calculated in the answer give in the link allows for the possibility that a car is seen in more than one window.

There are four 5-minute windows within the twenty minute window.
We can calculate the probabilities for different numbers of cars as follows, let $N$ be the number of 5-minute windows in which a car is seen and let $x$ be the probability of seeing a car in a 5-minute window.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(N=0) =& ^4C_0 (1-x)^4  = (1-x)^4 
\\
P(N=1) =& ^4C_1 x (1-x)^3 = 4 x (1-x)^3
\\
P(N=2) =& ^4C_2 x^2 (1-x)^2 =  6 x^2 (1-x)^2
\\
P(N=3) =& ^4C_3 x^3 (1-x) = 4 x^3 (1-x)
\\
P(N=4) =& ^4C_4 x^4  =  x^4
\end{aligned}
$$

We can easily confirm that the sum of these probabilities equals 1, they are the terms in the binomial expansion of $(1 + (1 -x))^4= 1^4 = 1$.

The expression for the  probability given in the linked answer is $1 - (1-x)^4$ which, in terms of the above, is equal to $1 - P(N=0)$. I.e. it represents the value of $P(N > 0)$ and does not represent the value of $P(N=1)$.

Comment: @ Paul Aljabar : What if $0.9$ is the probability of exactly one car passing through in the 20-min window!

Comment: Apologies, KGhatak, I had misunderstood the answer given in the link. I have changed my answer now.

Comment: @ Paul Aljabar : You previous explanation when $0.9$ is the probability of at least one car passing through in a 20-min window was awesome; and will be of great interests to many including me. May I request you to put that back in your response (e.g. current response when 0.9 is for exactly one car and previous response for at least one car). In the meantime, let me grasp your current response. Thanks a lot for taking the pain to explain it in details.